# Responsive section of fixed element

Tags: css, responsive-design

Total page width is 1200px. I have an element which has a width of 70% which would be 840px when max width is reached. I then have a left and right section in it. I want the left to stay at 40px and the remaining 800px to be responsive.

Do I make the remaining 800px a percentage of the 1200px or the 840px?

Comment: did you try [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

Make the left section 40px fixed width with `display: inline-block; overflow: hidden` and let the remainder auto size.

Comment: Cheers il look at it in the morning. Do i still float both elements?

Comment: Not having looked at your code I can't answer for sure, but if the two divs are contained within the same parent and have display inline-block, there should be no need to float. The first child will with such display property will always be on the left.